# Upstart not executing the exec function in upstart.conf

Tags: python, upstart, services

I have a completed upstart conf file loaded here: http://pastebin.com/5E7J5jEY but I'm having trouble with the upstart not executing the exec function and/or relinquishing the kernel console CLI back to me.

after executing `: sudo start itc_d` I get nothing back (no startup status or even a usable cursor).  If I use `ctrl+c` and run the command again I get: `start: Job is already running: itc_d`

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Perhaps something in my upstart config is wrong, or perhaps my python's createDaemon() function is not forking as expected? How can I fix/troubleshoot this issue?

**F.Y.I** - 
The file the upstart is attempting to execute is a python script that daemonizes itself (process forks twice) within the first function.  If you would like to see the python script here it is: http://pastebin.com/xLHEhg14 (the createDaemon() function is the one in question here)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `expect daemon` line from your upstart conf file.

I know it's *supposed* to be there according to the docs, but from my recent experience with python daemons (I'm currently using [this one](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/)), the [fork count](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#how-to-establish-fork-count) isn't incremented from python and so it will just hang.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
exec start-stop-daemon -S -c $uid:$gid -k $umask -x /usr/local/bin/python-daemon -- --app-options
```

No `expect`, just set the variables with `env`, start and stop levels, and then this exec.